# Jmeter - BeanShell assertion is not running

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

When running the thread, it goes through the whole flow except for the last BeanShell assertion.

[image]

My BeanShell code is:

```
report = vars.get("status_1");

if (report=="active") {

 Failure = true;
 FailureMessage = "failed to report";

} else {

    Failure = false;


}
```

What could go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing String using `==` you must use `.equals()` method to compare them.

That is generally true, not just for beanshell, but for most of the java world.  Always be careful about how you compare strings. see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: I was trying using this: `report = vars.get("status_1");

if (report.equals("active") {

 Failure = true;
 FailureMessage = "failed to report";
 
} else {

 Failure = false;
 
 
}`

But then for some reason it fails everything inside the IF controller

Comment: There are 2 beanshell assertions in your test plan, which one is this code for? Pay attention to the scope of an assertion. see this: http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/208250/file-989050882-png/Blog_Images/JMETERASSERTIONS-IMAGE1.png?t=1402378280830

Comment: Both "equals" and assertion scope helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can either use .equals() or boolean

```
 boolean report = vars.get("status_1");

 if (report) {

    Failure = true;
    FailureMessage = "failed to report";

  } else {

  Failure = false;


}
```